# How to use a stuck deodorant stick?

Tags: personal-care

I tried to use a brand new deodorant, and turns out it's stuck: it's just not possible to turn the wheel in the bottom of the deodorant in order to push it upwards. The wheel is jammed completely and does not turn at all.

This is how it looks like:

[image: image of deodorant]

The wheel/circle in the bottom is stuck, and can't be turned.

Is there any way to use the deodorant anyway? Would be pity to throw it away.

Comment: Do you mean that the wheel is jammed completely and does not turn at all or do you mean that you can turn it but it does not advance the plunger that pushes the (gel)? deodorant out of the top of the stick? If the latter, can you look through the case (or peel a label off) and see if the threaded rod up which the plunger rises does or does not turn when you turn the wheel?

Comment: @Caius the first option. Added to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Might also be a silly question, but have you tried turning the wheel both ways? I can't remember which way these turn to expel the gel - it's been many years since I had one

Comment: @Caius yes, and it should be clock-wise.

Answer (score 4):

If the stick is stuck to the sides of the container, you could try one or more of these to free it:

- Remove the cap and tap the stick against a hard surface.
- Submerge the whole stick (with cap on) in warm water to soften the plastic, and then either
- ... try the wheel again, or
- ... flex the tube to try and break the adhesion.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the container is made out of plastic, so it can be cut easily.

The following hacks may work.

1. Cut the container and fill the gel in an empty cream or petroleum jelly box, something like this.

[image]

So you can use your fingers and apply in armpits just like we take cream out of such box.

---

2. Or cut the container and fill the contents into empty glue sticks or lipstick boxes.

[image]

But this may require using more number of such glue sticks/lipsticks or store the entire contents in another container and refill them more frequently.

This method would be time consuming, you can apply the deodorant on a smaller area but still it may work.

Answer (score 3):

I pulled out the bottom wheel using some force along with the gear that isn't working.
Wrapped plumbers tape / plumbers hemp around the gear. Stuck it back. Now the gears are taking and doing it's work as it should.

Comment: Nice, not relevant anymore in my case but sounds useful for others. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this works and I've done it myself. +1 Welcome to Lifehacks.

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing the same thing, I found a solution by breaking off the wheel with a pocket knife, don't cut yourself, the wheel is very sturdy, then pushing the bottom stick in the opening slightly upwards with the blunt end of a pencil. I refused to resort to scraping out of the container everyday, haha. It doesn't slide back in when you apply it, either. I hope I saved someone's day.

Answer (score 0):

If the wheel is really stuck, and if you did not use the stick yet (at all), the best hack is to take it back at the shop and have it replaced. You might still get a replacement even if the stick is slightly used.

At the same time, learn the lesson to test the products you buy, before the actual purchase - or at least immediately after (depending on the specifics).

Comment: There is a thin copper cover which needs to be removed before using the deodorant - I already removed it, and it's kind of a "security seal" - having it ensures a new product. Without it people will know the product is used, and only few will agree to use such a product. Even without it, chance for the shop to accept it back is very low, and with it - I'm afraid such chance doesn't exist. If anything, using this direction I can contact the manufacturer of the product and complain it's flawed. If it was worth more than few bucks I might have done it, but it's not worth the time otherwise.

Comment: Actually, sealed or not, if the product is  not usable, they should replace it for free. Nowadays, all products are covered by guarantees. I received money back on some fruits, after i tried to eat some of them, and they were spoiled.

Comment: Well, you live in a better place... here it only applies to clothes and electronic stuff. Food and misc things like deodorant aren't covered as far as I know.